# Compact ListView for Semantic Zoom in Windows Store app

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

Right now my zoomout version looks like the following
[image]

and I want it to look like

[image]

I have tried using listView, GridView, ListLayout and GridLayout but no help. Also tried searching the web but though there are a few solution for C#/XAML version there is none for the JavaScript version.

Comment: What you'll want to do is to use a GridView. Create a single `ObservableCollection` that has items in it a) for each `Item` and b) for each `Group`. Then use a `DataTemplateSelector` to select the template that you want. It will be difficult to have it staggered like you have it in the bottom picture though (with the top row all lining up perfectly like that). Then just make sure that you are using a `WrapGrid` (likely a `VirtualizedWrapGrid`), and Voila!

Comment: Can you show some sample code that works with JavaScript version as I don't want a C# and XAML solution. I am very new to this.